# Is there a way to simulate multiple NVIDIA GPU cards when there is only one?

Tags: nvidia, cuda, gpu

I am working with some software that has been written assuming multiple GPUs present on the system. It is crashing for me with error message:

```
[09:39:34] src/storage/storage.cc:71: Check failed: e == cudaSuccess || e == cudaErrorCudartUnloading CUDA: invalid device ordinal
```

I have only one GPU card. Is there any way to trick CUDA so that it would only use that single card, rather than failing?

I can make changes in the source code to use the single device only, but I cannot commit such change to repository so currently need to do all testing on the branch, pulling changes periodically.

My OS is 4.18.0-18-generic #19~18.04.1-Ubuntu.

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: Sad to hear ...